# move images around in a google-like map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Before posting this question I did many tries and searched everywhere for alternatives, but I gave up and I'm asking here..

What is the easiest way to create an interactive map controlled by functions?
Here are details:

I have a div with fixed width/height, without a background, and I need to dynamically add things (images/text) inside of it, at any position, and they can also overlap each other if needed.

An example is better than thousand words:
- assuming the div is 500w 500h, I need to create an image at (200,200) with a size of 50x50

Here are the thousand words:
I tried with canvas, but it's too hard to remove something without touching the other things (for example if images #1 and #2 are overlapped and I want to delete the #1, I'll delete part of img #2 in the process. Of course the best thing would be to save things stored to when I need to delete something I can redraw all the rest, but it's a huge pain, if something easier exist would be better)

Tried also with http://leafletjs.com/index.html, but it seems too powerful to solve my problem, and I don't even know if it works without a background.

Maybe the best solution would be to use simple divs with good positioning, so I can change through functions their content easily, but I suck at div positioning.

Thank you to everyone that can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend the MapBox JavaScript API. It's a nifty utility that I have used in various instances. https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-javascript-api/ Extremely extendable API.